# The Difference Of Location Storage File in air

Tags: file-io, air, location, storage

I want to ask the difference between `air.File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath`, `File.userDirectory.resolvePath`, `air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath`..

Can anybody explain when does the file will be store.....

especially in windows

Answer (score 25):

AIR's applicationStorageDirectory will automatically target these locations depending on which OS the application is running:

- **Windows 7 / Vista:** c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\roaming\APPLICATIONNAME
- **Windows XP:** c:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application
  Data\APPLICATIONNAME
- **Mac OS X:** /Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/APPLICATIONNAME
- **Linux (Ubuntu):** /Users/USERNAME/.appdata/

along with desktopDirectory, documentsDirectory, applicationDirectory (read-only), which, too, have their own specific locations, these are built-in conveniences that allow AIR developers to produce cross-platform applications without having to know about (or specifically code for) the file system of a target OS.

Comment: I'd like to append the following if someone comes across this question more recently as I did:

In later versions of OS X, applicationStorageDirectory will be in /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/APPLICATIONNAME

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 you should include Victor's suggestion in your answer.

Answer (score 21):

*This info applies to AIR 1.0 and later (ActionScript 3.0)*

- **File.applicationStorageDirectory**: a storage directory unique to each installed AIR application. This directory is an appropriate place to store dynamic application assets and user preferences. Consider storing large amounts of data elsewhere. On Android and iOS, the application storage directory is removed when the application is uninstalled or the user chooses to clear application data, but this is not the case on other platforms.
- **File.applicationDirectory**: the directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets). On some operating systems, the application is stored in a single package file rather than a physical directory. In this case, the contents may not be accessible using the native path. The application directory is read-only.
- **File.desktopDirectory**: the user’s desktop directory. If a platform does not define a desktop directory, another location on the file system is used.
- **File.documentsDirectory**: the user’s documents directory. If a platform does not define a documents directory, another location on the file system is used.
- **File.userDirectory**: the user directory. If a platform does not define a user directory, another location on the file system is used.

If you specify a publisher ID in the AIR application descriptor, then the publisher ID is appended to the applicationID.

### Android

- **File.applicationDirectory** (read-only)

  `/data/data/`
- **File.applicationStorageDirectory**

  `/data/data/<applicationID>/<filename>/Local Store`
- **File.cacheDirectory**

  `/data/data/<applicationID>/cache`
- **File.desktopDirectory**

  `/mnt/sdcard`
- **File.documentsDirectory**

  `/mnt/sdcard`
- **temporary** - from `File.createTempDirectory()` and `File.createTempFile()`

  `/data/data/<applicationID>/cache/FlashTmp.<randomString>`
- **File.userDirectory**

  `/mnt/sdcard`

### iOS

- **File.applicationDirectory** (read-only)

  `/var/mobile/Applications/<uid>/<filename>.app`
- **File.applicationStorageDirectory**

  `/var/mobile/Applications/<uid>/Library/Application Support/<applicationID>/Local Store`
- **File.cacheDirectory**

  `/var/mobile/Applications/<uid>/Library/Caches`
- **File.desktopDirectory** - not accessible
- **File.documentsDirectory**

  `/var/mobile/Applications/<uid>/Documents`
- **temporary** - from `createTempDirectory()` and `createTempFile()`

  `/private/var/mobile/Applications/<uid>/tmp/FlashTmp<randomString>`
- **File.userDirectory** - not accessible

### Linux

- **File.applicationDirectory** (read-only)

  `/opt/<filename>/share`
- **File.applicationStorageDirectory**

  `/home/<userName>/.appdata/<applicationID>/Local Store`
- **File.desktopDirectory**

  `/home/<userName>/Desktop`
- **File.documentsDirectory**

  `/home/<userName>/Documents`
- **temporary** - from `createTempDirectory()` and `createTempFile()`

  `/tmp/FlashTmp.<randomString>`
- **File.userDirectory**

  `/home/<userName>`

### Mac

- **File.applicationDirectory** (read-only)

  `/Applications/<filename>.app/Contents/Resources`
- **File.applicationStorageDirectory** (AIR 3.2 and earlier)

  `/Users/<userName>/Library/Preferences/<applicationID>/Local Store`
- **File.applicationStorageDirectory** (AIR 3.3 and later)

  `/Users/<userName>/Library/Application Support/<applicationID>/Local Store`
- **File.applicationStorageDirectory** (AIR 3.3 and later) sandboxed

  `/Users/<userName>/Library/Containers/<bundleID>/Data/Library/Application Support/<applicationID>/Local Store`
- **File.cacheDirectory**

  `/Users/<userName>/Library/Caches`
- **File.desktopDirectory**

  `/Users/<userName>/Desktop`
- **File.documentsDirectory**

  `/Users/<userName>/Documents`
- **temporary** - from `createTempDirectory()` and `createTempFile()`

  `/private/var/folders/<userName?>/<randomString>/TemporaryItems/FlashTmp`
- **File.userDirectory**

  `/Users/<userName>`

### Windows

- **File.applicationDirectory** (read-only)

  `C:\Program Files\<filename>`
- **File.applicationStorageDirectory**

  `C:\Documents and settings\<userName>\ApplicationData\<applicationID>\Local Store`
- **File.cacheDirectory**

  `C:\Documents and settings\<userName>\Local Settings\Temp`
- **File.desktopDirectory**

  `C:\Documents and settings\<userName>\Desktop`
- **File.documentsDirectory**

  `C:\Documents and Settings\<userName>\My Documents`
- **temporary** - from `createTempDirectory()` and `createTempFile()`

  `C:\Documents and Settings\<userName>\Local Settings\Temp\<randomString>.tmp`
- **File.userDirectory**

  `C:\Documents and Settings\<userName>`

[Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html)

Comment: On Windows 10, File.applicationStorageDirectory is C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\<applicationID>\Local Store

Answer (score 1):

Copying from Victor's comment: In later versions of OS X, applicationStorageDirectory will be in /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/APPLICATIONNAME

This is the correct location in MAC OS in 2016

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TheDarkini1978's answer:

File.applicationDirectory is read only, don't try to save files there. `resolvePath` function creates file object with name relative to given file. When in doubt, always see the docs: [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)