# How Can I Save My XML File To A Specific Folder?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an app (Android & IOS) that contains an XML file (embedded with Adobe Flash in settings).

Any idea how to do these manipulations with AS3 code?

1. Find the exact URL of the xml file.
2. Move the xml file in a specific folder.

Here's what I've tried :

**1)** I've tried to load the file via `URLLoader` and then save it in a specific folder (without success).

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("soleil.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete_handler);

function complete_handler (event:Event) :void
{
    var myXML:XML;
    myXML = new XML(event.target.data);
    var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
    fr.save(myXML, 'soleil.xml');

    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    trace(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath);
    fileStream.open(new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"\\soleil.xml"),FileMode.WRITE);
}
```

The last line throws an error `Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid`:

```
fileStream.open(newFile(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+"\\soleil.xml"),FileMode.WRITE);
```

**2)** Just to know where is saved my embed xml file `soleil.xml`. But I think, it only creates a path...

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory; 
file = file.resolvePath("soleil.xml");
trace(file.url);
```

**EDIT 2 :**

The XML file contains data that I want to use.

What I was doing before using `File` was :

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("soleil.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processSoleil);

        function processSoleil(e:Event):void {
            myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var results:XMLList = myXML.row.(date == mySavedData.data.theDate);
    if(results.length()){

    for each(var row:XML in results){
        //doingstuff

    }
}
        }
```

Should I change my method ?

Now that I've managed to copy `soleil.xml` in a specific path by doing :

```
var packagedFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath( "soleil.xml" );
var destFile_soleilXML:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath( "soleil.xml" );
packagedFile.copyTo( destFile_soleilXML );
```

I though I could load the file by doing  :

```
myLoader.load(new URLRequest(destFile_soleilXML.nativePath));
```

Shouldn't I do that ?

At the moment I've got an error when trying to load my xml file (Stream error (apparently meaning that "file is not found" ) ).

Any tips ?

Comment: Doesn't Android use forward slashes like `+"//soleil.xml"`? Are they even needed here? Anyways what is the trace for `trace("Native Path : " + File.applicationDirectory.nativePath );`?

Comment: It's for tracing the ApplicationDirectory url in order to find where could be my soleil.xml file.

Comment: What's the output of the trace code from my first comment? Also that `.open` should have a `.READ` or `.APPEND` file mode, don't use `FileMode.WRITE` during a `fileStream.open`... I can't test anything Android at the moment, just trying to get a picture of your problem without having to test your code...

Comment: PS: Also it's confusing how `FileReference` let you use `applicationDirectory` to store the file (you got a "save file" pop-up? right). It should likely have put it at `File.documentsDirectory` or `File.userDirectory` but I don't know what you're seeing o your screen (_eg:_ what folder paths in file explorer).

Comment: See: **(1)** [**Possible storage locations**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130186/the-difference-of-location-storage-file-in-air/4131148#4131148) and also **(2)** [**How to save a mobile file in AIR**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29566275/2057709)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android your application files are packaged inside the APK and accessed directly from there. As these files are generally compressed there is no direct path (`nativePath`) to these files. You will need to use the `File` class to read / extract / copy the data.

Files packaged with your application are stored relative to the `File.applicationDirectory`:

```
var packagedFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath( "soleil.xml" );
```

To copy this to a location where you can get a native path. The best and most consistent place is the `File.applicationStorageDirectory`:

```
var destFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( "soleil.xml" );

packagedFile.copyTo( destFile );
```

You should now be able to access the native path of the copied file:

```
trace( destFile.nativePath );
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this accurate answer. Unfortunatley, now I try to load this xml but it throws an error... Here's what I did : `var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest(destFile.nativePath));`, but I've got this error : `Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/storage/emulated/0/soleil.xml`. Any idea why ?

Comment: @cocoGeek I don't understand what you're trying to do with the URLLoader; you already have access with the File object.  What are you trying to accomplish by loading with a URLLoader instead?

Comment: @cocoGeek `Stream Error` means _"File not found"_. Check if file actually exists at the URL.

Comment: Perhaps show the code you are using now, the `app:/` url reference looks wrong if you are using a native path you will have to prepend `file://` to load it through a url loader i believe.

Comment: I've edited my post in order to give you more details. thank you again for your help !

Comment: @Brian I've udapted my post

Comment: @Michael, I tested on a mobile device... so maybe that's why I've got `app:/` instead of `file://` ?

Comment: Why did you use `File.documentsDirectory` ? That directory requires requesting write permission for the public storage area and really shouldn't be used unless you know what you are doing. The copy is probably failing as you haven't requested read/write permission to that area. Try the `applicationStorageDirectory` as I suggested.

Comment: Same error : `Error #2032: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/data/user/0/air.nc.cocogeek.mareeNC/nc.cocogeek.mareeNC/Local%20Store/soleil.xml`

Comment: Still doesn't look right. You shouldn't have an `app://` scheme. Are you using the `file://` scheme in your request? ie. `new URLRequest( "file://"+destFile.nativePath);`